# Does Collection.stream() have internal synchronization?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-stream

I have been trying to reproduce (and solve) a `ConcurrentModificationException` when an instance of `HashMap` is being read and written by multiple `Thread`s.

Disclaimer: I know that `HashMap` is not thread-safe.

In the following code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        java.util.Map<String, Integer> oops = new java.util.HashMap<>();
        oops.put("1", 1);
        oops.put("2", 2);
        oops.put("3", 3);

        Runnable read = () -> {
            System.out.println("Entered read thread");

            /*
             * ConcurrentModificationException possibly occurs
             *
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
                numbers.addAll(oops.values());
                System.out.println("Size " + numbers.size());
            }
            */

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
                numbers.addAll(oops.values()
                        .stream()
                        .collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.toList()));
                System.out.println("Size " + numbers.size());
            }
        };

        Runnable write = () -> {
            System.out.println("Entered write thread");
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                System.out.println("Put " + i);
                oops.put(Integer.toString(i), i);
            }
        };

        Thread writeThread = new Thread(write, "write-thread");
        Thread readThread = new Thread(read, "read-thread");

        readThread.start();
        writeThread.start();

        readThread.join();
        writeThread.join();
    }
}
```

Basically, I make two threads: one keeps putting elements into a `HashMap`, the other is iterating on `HashMap.values()`.

In the `read` thread, if I'm using `numbers.addAll(oops.values())`, the `ConcurrentModificationException` randomly occurs. Though the lines are printed randomly as expected.

But if I switch to `numbers.addAll(oops.values().stream()..`, I don't get any error. However, I have observed a strange phenomenon. All the lines by the `read` thread are printed **after** the lines printed by the `write` thread.

My question is, does `Collection.stream()` have somehow internal synchronization?

**UPDATE**:

Using JDoodle https://www.jdoodle.com/a/IYy, it seems on JDK9 and JDK10, I will get `ConcurrentModificationException` as expected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is absolutely by chance; bear in mind that internally `System.out.println` does a `synchronzied`; thus *may be* that somehow makes it look like the results appear in order.

I have not looked too deep into your code - because analyzing why `HashMap`, which is not thread safe, is miss behaving is most probably futile; as you know, it is documented to be non-thread safe.

About that `ConcurrentModificationException`, the documentation is specific that it will *try* at best odds to throw that; so it's either java-8 was weaker in this point, or this was again by accident.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get `ConcurrentModificationException` with streams on Java 8 but with some changes in code: increased number of iterations and number of added elements to map in a separate thread from 100 to 10000. And also added `CyclicBarrier` so that loops in reader and writer threads are started more or less at the same time. I've also checked source code of spliterator for `Hashmap.values()` and it throws `ConcurrentModificationException` if some modifications to map were made.

```
if (m.modCount != mc) //modCount is number of modifications mc is expected modifications count which is stored before trying to fetch next element
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at the source code of Java 8 quickly, it does throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.
`HashMap`'s `values()`method returns a subclass of `AbstractCollection`, whose `spliterator()` method returns a `ValueSpliterator`, which throws `ConcurrentModificationException`.

For information `Collection.stream()` uses a spliterator to traverse or partition elements of a source.